# cannot build APK in android studio because of grade error Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: android, gradle

cannot build apk the following error appears.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/squareup/picasso/Action$RequestWeakReference.class

how to fix this

Comment: post gradle file please

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one picasso library, check if you have this `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` or `compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')` or `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` in your gradle file. You only need one them.